# How to return the original string in Java after using jquery.serialize()

Tags: java, jquery

I have a problem after serializing the form with jquery.
Why some text retain the html entities even after loaded to Java(Servlet)
For example I have a text & and it will return into %26 in Java.

I serialize and submit the form into Java using this..

```
function ajaxSubmit(frmN){
    var serForm = $(frmN).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'inser',
        data:{actionName : "insertField", formField : serForm},
        success: function(request){
            $("#reqContainer").html(request);
        }
    });
```

}

Is there a way to deserialize the html entities from java.
I guess I need first to split the & and then split the = 
to get the list of field and its value, and after that the
deserialization will begin.

I'll appreciate any help.
I read some article using JSON but I don't have time to study it.
If there is an alternative way submitting all the form values via
ajax with jquery, and will get the original
value from Java please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try JQuery form plugin? I remember a ajaxSubmit utility method.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Otherwise you could just use URLDecoder in java. This will change your ascii character back to its original string.

Comment: I haven't try using jquery.form.js and as much as possible I want to limit additional plugin. With regards to URLDecoder that maybe the solution but for now I need a quick solution. As of now I have no time to study some tutorials but I will be back to use URLDecoder after a week, after I present my module. For now I hard-coded some of the fields. So I can move forward on my development. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: UrlDecoder.decode(string). There is no need for you to go thro any tutorial ;)